Live server doesn't load like the templates of frameworks like Jinja or Vue.js
I don't know how does live server works per se, but when i use it to render html pages which include syntax and logic of templating engines like Jinja or Vue.js , instead of live server like implementing the logic behind the syntax , it just displays the syntax on the web page . For example in Vue.js we can use {{ v-bind:if (certain value greater than other display this) }} or in like jinja {{ if name.names == (John) }}  so like instead of displaying the logic it just displays the syntax above.. Why is that?
I reinstalled the Live Server extension hoping their might be an issue with that , Also one thing to note i use WSL on windows , so i thought maybe linux might be interfering with windows os ( has happened before to me ) I turned that off it also didn't Work.

Some of the live reloads are not aware of frameworks. I know that serve is and I remember that I needed to suffix some other ones with --spa. So, as a solution, I recommend either using serve or the default dev server with HMR baked into VueJS.
